# Integration over a $(0,1/b)$

Tags: calculus, integration

I try to compute the value of the following integral
$\int_0^{\frac{1}{b}}r^2(\frac{1}{r}-b)^{\frac{5}{2}}dr$
for b>0 Can you help me?

Best Regards.

Comment: The result is $\frac{5\pi}{16\sqrt{b}}$.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: The substitution $r\mapsto r/b$ yields $b^{-1/2}\int_0^1r^{-1/2}(1-r)^{5/2}\,\mathrm{d}r$ Not sure if that helps, because I don't know what prerequisites you have, what you've tried, etc. Please consider adding context as suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: @robjohn Well, if they aren't aware of the beta function, then it's the perfect opportunity to let them prove it! :P

Comment: @FrankW.: that's why we require context. Without context, we can fish around for a long time trying to figure out what the OP knows and where they've gotten stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your integral looks very similar to the Beta Function$$B(m,n)=\int\limits_0^1dt\, t^{m-1}(1-t)^{n-1}$$In order to get there, we first need to make the expression in the parenthesis equal to $1-t$. The first step is to factor out a $\frac 1r$ to get$$I=\int\limits_0^{1/b}dr\, r^{-1/2}(1-br)^{5/2}$$Now make a substitution $t=br$. Can you complete the rest?